# How to add 3 float type values and show on another field

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

How do I add 3 float type values and show on another field in OpenERP?

I need to add `c1`, `c2` and `c3` value and show on `c4` field.

Code sample below.

```
    _columns = {
         'c1':fields.float('value1'),
         'c2':fields.float('value2'),
         'c3':fields.float('value3'),
         'c4':fields.function(_get_total, string='value4', store=False),
    }

    def _get_total(self, cr,uid, ids, args, context=None):
        --------
        --------
        --------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a combination of these answers.

First define c4 as a functional field as specified in the answer from user1576199, then create the on_change function as defined in the answer from Atul;

```
def onchange_value(self, cr, uid, ids, c1 = 0.0, c2 = 0.0, c3 = 0.0, context = None):
     return {'value': {'c4': c1 + c2 + c3}}
```

but, put the on_change on the values c1 to c3, not c4, like this...

```
 <field name="c1" on_change="onchange_value(c1, c2, c3, context) />
 <field name="c2" on_change="onchange_value(c1, c2, c3, context)/>
 <field name="c3" on_change="onchange_value(c1, c2, c3, context)/>
 <field name="c4" />
```

c4 is a functional field but you can still return it in an on_change value clause for other field(s) and the value on the screen will be refreshed but it will not be stored in the database unless you add `store = True` to the c4 field definition.

If the user changes any of the c1, c2 or c3 fields, the on_change method will be called and the total will be re-calculated and refreshed on the display.

Comment: Yes I missed that part! :)
Updated the answer.

Comment: I want to multiply price with tax_id where tax_id is following 'tax_id': fields.many2many('account.tax', 'sale_order_tax', 'order_line_id', 'tax_id', 'Taxes'),                                      with the total like this total=price*tax_id

Answer (score 2):

One way is you can add a button and on click of that button call the method.

E.G.

Button in .xml:

```
  <button type="object" name="get_total" string="Calculate Total"/>
```

Method in .py:

```
  def get_total(self, cr, uid ,ids, context=None):
      so = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)[0]
      c4 = (so.c1 or 0.0) + (so.c2 or 0.0) + (so.c3 or 0.0)
      return self.write(cr, uid , ids, {'c4' : c4})
```

Regards,

Comment: or if you don't want to write value you can just return it without write for view purpose. :)

Comment: now i want to calculate TAX acording to openerp tax format so how can i multiply tax field in c4

Comment: Can you please provide some details that exactly what do you want to do so that we can help you. :)

Comment: I want to multiply price with tax_id where tax_id is following 'tax_id': fields.many2many('account.tax', 'sale_order_tax', 'order_line_id', 'tax_id', 'Taxes'),                                      with the total like this total=price*tax_id

Answer (score 2):

**Functional** field will only work when you save or edit value of c1, c2, c3 field, better to use `on_change`.
Here I give you some idea about `onchange`.

In the .py file create `onchange` method.

```
 _columns = {
         'c1':fields.float('value1'),
         'c2':fields.float('value2'),
         'c3':fields.float('value3'),
         'c4':fields.float('value4'),
    }

 def onchange_value(self, cr, uid, ids, c1=0.0, c2=0.0, c3=0.0, context=None):
     return {'value': {'c4': c1+c2+c3}}
```

and in xml file put a field in the form view like,

```
 <field name="c1" on_change="onchange_value(c1, c2, c3)"/>
 <field name="c2" on_change="onchange_value(c1, c2, c3)"/>
 <field name="c3" on_change="onchange_value(c1, c2, c3)"/>
 <field name="c4"/>
```

**Benifits**: it will change value of `c4` without saving record.

**Drawbacks** : field `c4` will be stored in the database.

Hope this helps!

Comment: now i want to calculate TAX acording to openerp tax format so how can i multiply tax field in c4

Comment: How do you get the TAX?

Comment: I want to multiply price with tax_id where tax_id is following 'tax_id': fields.many2many('account.tax', 'sale_order_tax', 'order_line_id', 'tax_id', 'Taxes'),                                      with the total like this total=price*tax_id

Answer (score 1):

what you do till is correct.

you just have to define function to show total of these three fields in one field.

```
   'c4': fields.function(_get_total, string='value4', type='float')

    def _get_total(self, cr, uid, ids, field_names, args, context=None):
        res = {}
        for line in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            res[line.id] = line.c1 + line.c2 + line.c3

   return res
```

Hope this help

Comment: I want to multiply price with tax_id where tax_id is following 'tax_id': fields.many2many('account.tax', 'sale_order_tax', 'order_line_id', 'tax_id', 'Taxes'),                                      with the total like this total=price*tax_id